# how to write a loop to replace all nan values using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, group-by

I have this: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thedevastator/global-fossil-co2-emissions-by-country-2002-2022 dataset with lots of nan values,
in country there are many duplicate values that I need them.
I want to groupby the 'Country' column and then get each country's other columns(total, Coal, per capita...) mean value and replace them into original dataframe. is there any way to do this?

I wrote a peace of code but I can not develop it:

```
countryunique = df['Country'].unique()
dc = df.groupby('Country').mean().reset_index()


for b in dc['Country']:
    for i in countryunique:
        if (b == i):
            df['Total'] = df.fillna(dc['Country'][b])
```

I tried this but this is not true

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'Country' and col !='ISO 3166-1 alpha-3' and col!='Year':
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(str(df[col].mean()))
```

Comment: hi. your question is a bit unreadable. maybe adding information about `df` and `dc` would provide more readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to calculate the mean of all columns based on country right?

I don't know if it's okay, but I'm using pivot_table() instead of groupby()

```
df = pd.read_csv('GCB2022v27_MtCO2_flat.csv')
dc = df.pivot_table(index=['Country', 'ISO 3166-1 alpha-3'], aggfunc='mean').reset_index()
```

this is the output
[image: Output]

Comment: and for the "Year" column, I think it would be better if you convert it to a range first so you can use it as an index as well

Comment: then for the nan values just use df['Your column here'].fillna('Your values here')

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna` after to compute `mean`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('GCB2022v27_MtCO2_flat.csv')
df = df.fillna(df1.groupby('Country')[df.columns[4:].transform('mean'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           Country ISO 3166-1 alpha-3  Year         Total          Coal           Oil          Gas       Cement     Flaring       Other  Per Capita
0      Afghanistan                AFG  1750      0.000000      0.790089      1.802428     0.277625     0.034475    0.081590         NaN    0.151478
1      Afghanistan                AFG  1751      0.000000      0.790089      1.802428     0.277625     0.034475    0.081590         NaN    0.151478
2      Afghanistan                AFG  1752      0.000000      0.790089      1.802428     0.277625     0.034475    0.081590         NaN    0.151478
3      Afghanistan                AFG  1753      0.000000      0.790089      1.802428     0.277625     0.034475    0.081590         NaN    0.151478
4      Afghanistan                AFG  1754      0.000000      0.790089      1.802428     0.277625     0.034475    0.081590         NaN    0.151478
...            ...                ...   ...           ...           ...           ...          ...          ...         ...         ...         ...
63099       Global                WLD  2017  36096.739276  14506.973805  12242.627935  7144.928128  1507.923185  391.992176  302.294047    4.749682
63100       Global                WLD  2018  36826.506600  14746.830688  12266.016285  7529.846784  1569.218392  412.115746  302.478706    4.792753
63101       Global                WLD  2019  37082.558969  14725.978025  12345.653374  7647.528220  1617.506786  439.253991  306.638573    4.775633
63102       Global                WLD  2020  35264.085734  14174.564010  11191.808551  7556.290283  1637.537532  407.583673  296.301685    4.497423
63103       Global                WLD  2021  37123.850352  14979.598083  11837.159116  7921.829472  1672.592372  416.525563  296.145746    4.693699

[63104 rows x 11 columns]
```

For remaining NaN values, you can chain another `.fillna(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, for each country you want to replace the missing values of the columns `["Total", "Coal", "Oil", "Gas", "Cement", "Flaring", "Other"]` by the country's average of those columns.

I would do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

metrics = ["Total", "Coal", "Oil", "Gas", "Cement", "Flaring", "Other"]
average_by_metrics = df.groupby("Country")[metrics].mean()

def fill_missing_values(row, col):
    if np.isnan(row[col]):
        return average_by_metric[row["Country"], col]
    else:
        return row[col]

for col in metrics :
    df[col] = df.apply(lambda row: fill_missing_values(row, col), axis=1)
```